# Differential Gronwall

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Wikipedia states that if $u^{\prime}(t) \leq B(t)u(t)$, $u(t)$ is bounded by the solution of the corresponding differential equality $v^{\prime}(t) = B(t)v(t)$.  I am not exactly sure what it means by "bounded;" does this mean that $u(t) \leq v(t)$ for all $t$?  If so, is it also true that $u^{\prime}(t) \geq B(t)u(t)$ implies $u(t) \geq v(t)$, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is what it means . The reason is that if you have two differentiable functions with $f(a)=g(a)$ and $f’(x)\le g’(x)$ for $x>a$ then $f(x)\le g(x)$ for $x>a$ (just integrate from $a$ to $x$). This is how you construct lower and upper barriers for solutions to differential inequalities.